# How to use quick.db variable in client.users.fetch discordjs

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

I am trying to use a value (Discord User ID stored as a string) stored via quick.db in my code, but it returns me the error `user_id: Value "[object Promise]" is not snowflake.` I've spent hours trying to figure it out but it just doesn't work. If I store the ID directly in the code it works just fine and I can fetch the user.

This is my "ready.js" file. The cron package lets me define at what time of the day that part of code is being executed. I don't think it's a part of the problem.

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js")
    const cron = require('cron');
    const path = require('path');
    const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
    const db = new QuickDB()
    
    module.exports = client => {
    
      console.log(`${client.user.username} ist online`)
      client.user.setActivity('Online!', { type: 'PLAYING' });
      
        let userid1 = db.get("id1.string");
        let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('00 00 08 * * *', () => {
        client.users.fetch(userid1).then(user => {
          user.send('Test').catch(err => {
            let channel = client.channels.cache.get('998568073034465341')
            channel.send(`${user} blocked the bot`)
                  })
                })
            })
      scheduledMessage.start()
      }
```

This is where I want to utilize a User ID stored via quick.db in "id1.string"

```
client.users.fetch(userid1).then(user => {
```

-> This doesn't work

```
client.users.fetch(400120540989227010).then(user => {
```

-> This is working fine

I've already tried using

```
`${userid1}`
```

but this also doesn't work

I'd be so happy if someone could help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.get("id1.string")` is an async function, meaning unless you put `await` behind it, it will returns a Promise who isn't finished yet. It's like wanting to send a discord message. You can't just get the message immediatly since because of your connection and the api's connection. It takes time. So to bypass this you have to use the `await` keyword before the .get method (and async the main function here) so that it won't execute the rest of the code until you get what you want from the database.

```js
let userid1 = db.get("id1.string"); // What you have now
let userid1 = await db.get("id1.string"); // What you should do instead
```

```js
module.exports = client => { // What you have now 
module.exports = async client => { // What you should do instead
```